# How can I interpret this C++ error

Tags: c++

I have this line of code (line is of type string):

```
char* p = line.data;
```

Before you respond, I already figured out what I was doing wrong, I needed some parentheses at the end.  What I want to ask you is how I am supposed to interpret the error I got for future reference:

`error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::data<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ from type ‘const char* (std::basic_string<char>::)()const noexcept (true)’ to type ‘char*’`

so first I must ask, could this possibly be more confusing?  How on earth do you C++ developer's cope with stuff like this?  Thank heaven for higher level languages right?  OK so all of those questions were just rhetorical.

OK so I have read this error about a dozen times now.  I also reviewed the string data method documentation, and it does say that it returns a char*.  So I am confused about the following:

1. Referring to this:

   ```
   basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>
   ```

According to the basic_string documentation, it has one template parameter, but this error seems to be saying there are three: _CharT, _Traits, and _Alloc.  Why does this basic string have three template parameters when the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) says it has one?  I guess I don't understand how to interpret that documentation or that error message.

1. Then it looks like the data portion also has template parameters,

   ```
   ...::data<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
   ```

but according to the 'data' method documentation, it is defined like this:

```
    const char* data() const noexcept;
```

I don't see any template parameters in that definition.  Why does the error message show all of these template parameters?

1. Then it gets more confusing, the error message says it's trying to cast from type:

   ```
   const char* (std::basic_string<char>::)()const noexcept (true)
   ```

so I think this is C++'s way of describing a function type, is that right?  Why does it end with the word true in parentheses?

So I guess I'm mainly trying to figure out why the C++ exceptions have all of these bizarre template parameters that I don't see in any documentation.

Comment: The other two are defaulted, as seen in a reference for [`std::basic_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/). `std::string` only uses the first of the three in its typedef. And the `(true)` is part of `noexcept`. It's `noexcept(true)`, which is the same as `noexcept`. Anyway, adding parentheses does not solve the problem alone. `char *` cannot hold a `const char *` result. And FWIW, Clang's error is much better: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4c05741e00028e8

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I needed to add 'const' to the start, like you said.

Comment: good point, C++ compiler errors are (unfortunately still) most of the time not very informative, to say the least. add templates and all hell breaks loose. by seing the error again and again you "learn" what it really means

Comment: I don't know, I think that error message is quite informative. It told you exactly what it couldn't do; cast a function pointer with a specific signature to a ``char *``. What would you expect that error message to say?

Comment: @aruisdante, Perhaps something like *reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?*

Comment: @Chris: I never knew about that coliru website, that's awesome.  I think I could have figured this out much faster with that error message.

Comment: @msknapp, Coliru is great, but the real winner for the error message is Clang. Perfectly usable outside of Coliru. As others have said, the errors make gradually more sense with more experience and exposure. Those scary many-line template errors aren't usually too bad once you get to know them.

Comment: But that's making a lot of assumptions about what you're trying to do. Who is to say you didn't mean to use ``&line::data``? That's just as valid a thing to assume you meant to do as call a function when assigning to a pointer. GCC tends to err on the side of telling you *exactly* what went wrong, rather than assuming what you meant to do.

Comment: @aruisdante, As I recall, Clang does offer that as a suggestion other times (or maybe I'm thinking of GCC; I know I've seen "use &Foo::bar to create a pointer to member"), but not here it seems.

Comment: Also if you think that's a scary template expansion in an error message, wait until you mess up something involving boost and the error message is 20 lines long :p

Comment: @aruisdante, for one, I think the whole way it expresses a function could not be more confusing.  With "const char* (std::basic_string::)()const noexcept (true)" you have a scope operator '::' followed by an end parentheses?  extremely confusing.  Secondly, it seems like the error message tells you the type that this is twice: cannot convert '...' from type '...'.  Wait a minute, if that second part is the type, WTH is the first part?  Some way of saying what this instance is?  And to make it worse you have three template parameters for what is supposed to be a simple string.

Comment: @msknapp, Unfortunately, GCC doesn't clear up typedefs of templates very well. It uses the actual type. Anyway, the first part is the function (`data`) all spelled out as exactly what it is. The second is its type.

Comment: With respect to the function syntax in the error message, that's because it's all the information the compiler needs to determine compatible function types. ``const char*`` is the return type, ``std::basic_string::`` is the class it's bound to, ``()`` is the argument type list, and ``const`` is the fact that it's a const method, and ``noexcept (true)`` is the throw specifier. It excludes the name because the name isn't part of the function signature specification for determining the validity of a pointer assignment. If that makes sense.

Comment: A big clue is `const char* (std::basic_string<char>::)()const noexcept (true)` . You should recognize this as a *function type*, from which you can deduce that the problem is that you named a function when you meant to call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you provided seems to be heavily misquoted (or mangled by the parser). GCC produces the following

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::data<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ from type ‘const char* (std::basic_string<char>::)()const’ to type ‘char*’
```

1. I don't know what documentation told you that `std::basic_string` has only one template parameter. It has three.
2. The class itself and the member function of the class are *independent* templates. So `basic_string` is a template class and member function `basic_string::data()` is a separate template function. The error message gives you the full name of that `data` template function

   ```
   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::data<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
   ```

   The first part

   ```
   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>
   ```

   is just the class name, while the rest is the template function with the actual template arguments listed after the function name. This is in no way a perfect way to refer to this template. Most likely it is somehow derived from the inner workings of the compiler.
3. The "cast from function type" part has no logic in it from the language point of view. From the point of view of C++ language, `line.data` is not a valid expression at all. Hence it has no type. 
   However, apparently the inner workings of GCC compiler treat that combination as an expression of member function type. The error message actually shows that type as

   ```
   const char* (std::basic_string<char>::)()const
   ```

   Other compilers are also known to do that. Again, this is just inner mechanics of the compiler showing through.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the misconception of only one template parameter came from the typedef being `typedef basic_string<char> string;`

Comment: @chris: that's exactly how I came to that conclusion.  I was looking at the documentation for string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ but apparently I should have been looking at the basic_string page.

Comment: @msknapp The thing you have to remember is that a lot of the STL that is exposed as the primary interface is actually just typedefs/specializations of more generic base types. So yeah, sometimes you get some really odd looking template expansions.

Answer (score 2):

In practical terms, the way C++ programmers deal with this is by making the same error repeatedly enough times that they can generally recognise the "shape" of the error message rather than having to read it in detail.

Usually what I do when I get an error on a source line, is look to see whether I've done something dumb (without reading the error message in detail). Only if that fails and I can't see it, then I read the error message and see what the compiler is complaining about. Sometimes it's still inscrutable and I have to go back to looking for something dumb. In extreme cases this might happen a few times before I figure it out.

Comment: This is definitely true for many common issues.  You see it enough times and just know what the problem is even though the error message is still terrible to try and decipher.